# Handle barcode scanner value via Android device

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to handle value from a barcode scanner USB via my Android 3.2 tablet, the scanner is succefuly working in the OS but i want to get the value in the program without a edittext, usbmanager host and accessory did not list it with the connected devices via USB.

Comment: Which Bar Code scanner are you using? I am also working on same kind of project, It will be helpful for me.

Comment: I also had same problem. Please check my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69105676/13321079)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

most plug in barcode scanners (that I've seen) are made as HID profile devices so whatever they are plugged into should see them as a Keyboard basically. I think this is why they do not show up in the USB host APIs list of accessories. You should be able to get raw input from them the same way you would a keyboard inside your Activity by overriding [Activity.onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent ke)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

Something like this in your activity:

```
@Override
protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     Log.i("TAG", ""+ keyCode);
     //I think you'll have to manually check for the digits and do what you want with them.
     //Perhaps store them in a String until an Enter event comes in (barcode scanners i've used can be configured to send an enter keystroke after the code)
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: @BlackBird_K Is any Arduino board is used as middle man for Communication?

Comment: I tried this and worked but i had to press a button in barcodescanner. Can i do it programatically, then user does not need to press. It automatically detect and scan?

Comment: I have a barcode scanner that sends Enter event on marshmellow but not on IcreaCream...any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

you will get the result on Activity keydown event.

For Example:-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
    Barcode += "" + pressedKey;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "barcode--->>>" + Barcode, 1)
            .show();
    return true;
}
```

Hope this post will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem,but when i used onKeyDown or onKeyUp,it was not called every time i mean for every character for barcode.I Used DiapatchKeyEvent,and it worked nice.

Comment: Maybe should you consider giving an exemple?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("TAG", event.getCharacters());
    return true;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

`dispatchKeyEvent` can be used instead of `onKeyDown`.
Because, **dispatchKeyEvent** will pass the event to **onKeyListener** if there is activity. This is when **onKey** is called.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
  int c=event.getUnicodeChar();
  Log.d("C:", "" + c);
}
```