# How to access scanning result from barcode scanner connected to Android device via USB port?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

An external Laser barcode scanner is connected to Android POS device. I need to access the scanning result in my application. How is it possible? Need support from Android OS version 2.3 onwards.

Comment: I have this question too, I want too receive bluetooth scanner result programmatically by BluetoothAdapter or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

Most USB scanners connect via the HID profile, so Android should recognize it as a keyboard. The decoded barcode will be "typed" into the currently selected field.

If you'd like to capture the result without entering it into an editable field, see [Handle barcode scanner value via Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349542/handle-barcode-scanner-value-via-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

***Note: I'm using a handheld device (called: NBP-65)(using its SDK -> iScan SDK), so maybe you need to check if the device you're using has intent extra to get data from it such as `android.intent.action.SCANRESULT` in my case.***

---

I'd a similar issue. I needed to get data from Handheld android (QR scanner device).
You can get scanning result from barcode scanner by registering a broadcast receiver for the **action** `android.intent.action.SCANRESULT` and get the extra data using **key** `value`.
So the receiver will be like that

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCANRESULT")) {
            String qrCode = intent.getStringExtra("value");
            int barocodelen = intent.getIntExtra("length", 0);
            String type = intent.getStringExtra("type ");
            byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra("bytedata");
        }
    }
};
```

And register your receiver using register method (or you can register your receiver in the manifest file)

```
registerReceiver(receiver, newIntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCANRESULT"));
```

Comment: There is no way android has a specific intent called "android.intent.action.SCANRESULT" for this. This works in your case because your device has a specific implementation that broadcasts an intent when scanned. This shouldn't be an answer or at least should be stated which device you're using.

Comment: @Farid I updated the answer. Thanks.